# OpenWRT debugging wifi AP on the rpi4

Tags: openwrt

openwrt newbie here. I've installed OpenWRT on a rpi 4 and I can not bring up the wifi as an ap. Unfortunately "it's not working" and I'm unclear of how this should be debugged.

Actions taken:

1. Configure AP
2. Try to see the SSID from another device

Notes:

1. On my normal rpi AP, I just do a NAT and it works without much fuss
2. On this device, I can't see any obvious errors...
3. I've seen some references to a firmware update being required. I've applied it and no change...

```
root@mdr-ap1:~# cat /etc/config/wireless 

config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '36'
    option hwmode '11a'
    option path 'platform/soc/fe300000.mmcnr/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:0001/mmc1:0001:1'
    option htmode 'VHT80'
    option country 'US'
    option disabled '1'

config wifi-iface 'wifinet0'
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'OpenWrt1'
    option encryption 'none'
    option network 'lan'
    option disabled '1'
```

Comment: I've also been running into this issue. I've found various configs online that supposedly work, but I haven't had any luck getting another device to see the SSID.

Comment: The first "option disabled '1'" must be changed to "option disabled '0'". The second one can be deleted.